# Does JavaFX Scene Builder support the <fx:define> tag?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

If I try to use the fx:define tag in an fxml file, e.g.

```
<fx:define>
   <Tooltip fx:id="thetip" prefWidth="120" wrapText="true" text="Here's a tip of the day: prefWidth and wrapText attrs control the behavior of the tip."/>
</fx:define> 
<Button tooltip="${thetip}" text="Tip Button" />
```

(Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements)

... that does not work with the Scene Builder and I retrieve an error message (see below) when I try to open the fxml file.

Does the Scene Builder support the fx:define tag at all?

- If yes: how can I use it correctly?
- If no: where can I find a list with all tags that are (not) supported by the Scene Builder?

---

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: /D:/workspace/PowerTools/src/isi/power/tools/gui/manager/ScenarioManager.fxml:24
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:80)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:447)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:427)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/workspace/PowerTools/src/isi/power/tools/gui/manager/ScenarioManager.fxml:24
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.endElement(FXOMLoader.java:304)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2842)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 does not support the fx:define tag. Oracle stopped to provide binaries for the scene builder.
- Recent versions of the scene builder can be found here:
   
  http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/ 
  (Also see [Where exactly can I download the latest version of Scene Builder for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808130/where-exactly-can-i-download-the-latest-version-of-scene-builder-for-java)) 
   Version 8.1.1 (2016-02-04) neither supports the fx:define tag.

Comment: Still true, I think. Got the same problem with 8.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my error message was on a different line than the define, so I moved the define to the end of the file, and it then seemed to work just fine.

UPDATE: I can't seem to get it to work now, but I can get it to work if I remove the fx:define, edit with scenebuilder, then put the fx:define back

Comment: It is not working for me. Could you please provide an fxml file that contains <fx:define> and that can be opened with the scene builder?