# Where exactly can I download the latest version of Scene Builder for Java?

Tags: java, scenebuilder

I've searched around Oracle's sites and cannot find the actual executable to download. I get sites that point to older versions, or to the source of Scene Builder instead. I'm looking for the actual windows/mac executable installer for the latest version of Scene Builder.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here are both  version 1.x and 2.x scene builders
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html

This project was moved to openjfx project. So you can get the latest source code and any other version from http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx

This is the scene builder for jdk 8u40
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/5fc0ddb42776/apps/scenebuilder

Comment: Thank you very much. I've looked at that page and see this text right at the top: "WARNING: These versions of JavaFX Scene Builder may include components that do not contain the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production." and "For current Java releases, please consult the Oracle Software Download page."  Doesn't this mean that the versions of Scene Builder on this page are the older versions? So where is the Scene Builder version recommended for production?

Comment: @Zareh I've added the location for scen builder for jdk 8u40. you can find any other version from it's repositories

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. Forgive me for asking, but how exactly do I download this source and compile it? I'm using the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Zareh you should read the documentation. there is a complete guide on building openjfx. [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I looked at the link you provided. I agree with the first sentence on the link "Building a UI toolkit for many different platforms is a complex and challenging endeavor.". Unfortunately I don't have the time to go through all the steps to build my own version of Scene Builder just to have a production ready build of it. I'll stick with Window Builder and Swing until Scene Builder is production ready. Thanks again.

Answer (score 52):

Sadly, Oracle has decided to no longer provide binary downloads for Scene Builder. Their reasoning, as far as I can tell, seems to be that the main goal for the scene builder project is now to provide the SceneBuilderKit for integration inside IDEs (and IDE developers will, of course, compile it themselves) rather than the stand-alone SceneBuilderApp.

However, since Scene Builder has been open sourced, third parties can provide binary builds for download. One I'm aware of is Gluon; you can check out [their downloads page](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). The version they currently offer is recent enough to support the new controls included in the JDK 8u40.

For more information, you may want to read the discussions about 8u40 release on [the openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2015-March/thread.html#16748).

Comment: Thank you very much for your post. That's sheds some light on things. I was quite puzzled regarding why it was so hard to find a current executable installer for Scene Builder. Since I use the Eclipse IDE, I'll wait for them to incorporate it into Eclipse, much like WindowBuilder for Swing was eventually incorporated into Eclipse. Again, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Besides not having any straight integration with Eclipse (AFAIK), Scene Builder is a good tool. The best integration I'm aware of is with Netbeans. Anyway, if you can stay away from SWT/GWT/Swing (i.e. if you don't need any really low level graphics api), you should stick with JavaFX. Not as fast as the others, but the learning curve is ok and i'd say it's "production ready enough", for me.

Comment: Sheesh ! One could think they would at least bundle a built version of scne builder inside Netbeans.

Answer (score 24):

Recent builds can also be found here: 
http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Besides a runnable jar, they provide native installers as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a handy link to have.

Answer (score 6):

You can download the latest version of screen builder from the following URL according to your platform 
http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully pulled and compiled Scene Builder from here:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/a607b58ec579/apps/scenebuilder

Althought it's dev branch, dev build proved to be pretty stable.