# JavaFx Error "Unable to Open file" with SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx

An error message appears when opening fxml file with SceneBuilder.
The error: "opening the file with scene builder failed. Try setting the absolute path to scenebuilder in your the preferences."

I did not see the SceneBuilder in my Program files to configure in Path.

Comment: Thanks @Павел Бивойно,
Your approach works.
For windows users, one should first download an installer from https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the recent builds of scenebuilder at http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/

Edit:
Have a look at the stackoverflow post here:
[Where exactly can I download the latest version of Scene Builder for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808130/where-exactly-can-i-download-the-latest-version-of-scene-builder-for-java)

There is the explanation why you cant find scenebuilder on JavaFX 8. The post of Cyäegha explains it.

Comment: I should imagine because it does not fully answer the question directly. The problem is not about having the latest version of SceneBuilder, it's eclipse not knowing where to find it.

Answer (score -1):

In case Eclipse. Select your project, then Properties–>FXGrap–>Configure Workspace Setting–> JavaFX–>SceneBuilder executable –>Browse, and find path to SceneBuilder.exe