# Does Oracle still develop JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, obsolete

If you look at [JavaFX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html), it's at version 2.0 since:  2014-03-21 09:29.
It's also kinda hard to find it on Oracle's website. There is no Wikipedia page for it, so I want to ask, is it decrepit, obsolete? I want to use it for desktop GUI development.

Comment: Related (possibly duplicating): [Where exactly can I download the latest version of Scene Builder for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808130/where-exactly-can-i-download-the-latest-version-of-scene-builder-for-java) and [Where is the JavaFX scene builder gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880785/where-is-the-javafx-scene-builder-gone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is being maintained by Oracle, but builds are being made available by Gluon here: http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

Comment: I guess the precise question would be whether there is still active development going on or whether it is just in maintenance mode?